# pandas conditional with .loc to combine rows by concatenating strings

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe in which some of the data spills in to the next row, for example with **2-(Acetyloxy)-1-phenylethanone,** the 'none' goes to the next row, also the solubility is in three rows, so ends up looking like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([
    ['90', '2-(Acetyloxy)-1-phenyletha-', 'i H2O; vs EtOH,'], 
    [np.nan, 'ne', 'eth, chl; sl bz,'], 
    [np.nan, np.nan, 'lig']], 
    columns=['number', 'name', 'solubility'])

    number    name                          solubility
0   90        2-(Acetyloxy)-1-phenyletha-   i H2O; vs EtOH,
1   NaN       none                          eth, chl; sl bz,
2   NaN       NaN                           lig
```

I would like to form a function that searches for if the solubility column is not null and then combine the row with the one above it. Running the .loc below generates rows 1 and 2, 'number' **is null**, and 'solubility' is **not null**

```
In
    df.loc[df['number'].isnull() & df['solubility'].notnull()]

Out 
    number    name                          solubility
1   NaN       none                          eth, chl; sl bz,
2   NaN       NaN                           lig
```

How do I concatetate row 1 string with the row 0 string, also skipping NaNs? I thought groupby but no column contains unique values.

Comment: your goal is not clear to me. Does that .loc do what you want to? and what exactly do you want to concatenate and when?

Comment: I want to first determine the rows in 'number' that contain NaN so that I can then concatenate the two rows of the name, so "2-(Acetyloxy)-1-phenyletha-" + "none", and the 3 rows in solubility in to one string so " i H2O; vs EtOH," + "eth, chl; sl bz," + "lig" so that row 0 contains the full name and full list of items in solubility. This is just 1 chemical but there are hundreds of instances of this occurring.

Comment: btw, for row id 1, the dataframe definition has 'ne', while the text-data is showing 'none', i used your df definition and result is according to it

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
# use number to group together the rows
df['number'].ffill(inplace=True)

# make the null value as empty
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

# groupby on number and combine the name and solubility as a single row
df.groupby(['number'], as_index=False)[['name','solubility']].agg({'name': ''.join, 'solubility': ''.join } )
```

```
    number  name    solubility
0   90  2-(Acetyloxy)-1-phenyletha-ne   i H2O; vs EtOH,eth, chl; sl bz,lig
```

PS: for row id 1, the dataframe definition has 'ne', while the text-data is showing 'none', i used your df definition and result is according to it